# Realtime update Constraints

Tags: swift, constraints

How can i update constraint by tap on the image?

Sorry for the illiterate speech, I just started learning English, just like swift)

How can i update constraints by tap on the image, especially height and width. Please, see the code below. I try to set new value of height and width variables when i tap on the image, and i want the image to become bigger in REALTIME. But is don,t work. Please Help. P.S. Please dont ask me why i need it, just training, and i know what i can do it by CGAfflinetransorm...Thanks

```
import UIKit

class View: UIView {

    let image = UIImageView()
    var width: CGFloat = 150
    var height: CGFloat = 150

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect())
        backgroundColor = .systemGray
        image.backgroundColor = .black
        image.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")!
        
        addSubview(image)
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([image.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                                     image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                                     image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height),
                                     image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let mainView = View()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTap))
        mainView.image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        mainView.image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view = mainView
        
    }

    @objc func imageTap() {
       
        mainView.height = 300
        mainView.width = 300
        mainView.image.updateConstraints()
        mainView.image.layoutIfNeeded()
        
     
        
        print("work")
    }

}
```

Comment: The trouble is that this code does _not_ update any constraints. You can't just change some numbers. You need to reach right down into the image view (`mainView.image`), find its height and width constraints, and change them!

Comment: The easiest way to do that is to delete your height and width CGFloat properties and replace them with NSLayoutConstraint properties.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt says in the comments, the key to this is to work with constraints throughout, rather than trying to mix in absolute dimensions on your view.

You can wrap all the functionality up in the view, rather than having the gesture recogniser in the parent, although you will need to constrain the imageView to the dimensions of its parent view (rather than just to  its centre) so that updating the image size will also update the parent view's dimensions to accommodate the growth.

You will need to store the width constraint for the image size as a property so you can access it in the `imageTap()` method.  The example below assumes the image will always be a square, but you could store and manipulate height and width in a similar way if you didn't want them equal.

```
class View: UIView {
   
   let image = UIImageView()
   let inset = 0.0
   var imageWidthDimension: NSLayoutConstraint!
   
   init() {
      super.init(frame:.zero)
      image.backgroundColor = .black
      image.image = UIImage(systemName: "circle")!
      translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      
      addSubview(image)
      
      let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTap))
      image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
      
      image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      imageWidthDimension =  image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0)
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: inset),
         image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -inset),
         image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: inset),
         image.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -inset),
         imageWidthDimension,
         image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.widthAnchor),
      ])
   }
   
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
   
 
   @objc func imageTap() {
      imageWidthDimension.constant = 250.0 
      image.updateConstraints()
   }
}
```

Comment: @Ogogo If it's solved your problem, you should accept the answer by clicking the tick.